# Pass on graphical parameters through a new function

Tags: r, plot

I'm writing a function in R that includes options for plotting, using the base R `plot()` function. How does one "pass on" graphical parameters from a new function into the `plot()` function?

See the example below:

```
test.plot <- function(dat.x, dat.y, ...) { #Function with two parameters, pass on graphical parameters

  plot(x = dat.x,                          # Plot data
       y = dat.y)                          # Do graphical input parameters go here?

}

test.plot(dat.x = c(5.4, 2.7, 3.3, 2.1),
          dat.y = c(0.2, 1.9, 0.5, 1.3),
          xlab = "test axis")              # I want this graph to have the x label I put in
```

Any ideas?

Comment: may be you are looking for this: `?par`

Comment: par() doesn't seem to have options for xlab, main, type, etc. Must I define these with separate functions like axis()?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `...` into `plot()`.

```
test.plot <- function(dat.x, dat.y, ...) {

  plot(x = dat.x,
       y = dat.y, ...)

}

test.plot(dat.x = c(5.4, 2.7, 3.3, 2.1),
          dat.y = c(0.2, 1.9, 0.5, 1.3),
          xlab = "test axis",
          col = "red",
          pch = 10,
          cex = 5)
```

Comment: Thank you Darren. That seems to have worked. I appreciate you taking the time to share your expertise.